# Crontab problem

Tags: debian, cron

under debian as a root (using su -)

First of all there is already a job inside the server (done by someone else), when I type

```
crontab -e
```

I get

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * sh /opt/somescript.sh
```

It executes exery minute.

Anyway, I am trying to add a scheduled job to the crontab:
I want tried to add a second job that will be executed every day at 00:30 am.

```
30 0   * * *    sh /opt/newscript.sh
```

I have two problems:

- I am  not able to edit the crontab with `crontab -e`
- Is my newscript scheduling right ?

Answer (score 2):

your scheduling is right. i'm not sure why you can't edit the crontab. do you get any error message?

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting something like:

```
crontab: you are not authorized to use cron.  Sorry.
```

Add your username to `/etc/cron.allow` (or `/etc/cron.d/cron.allow`, depending on your setup).

You didn't mention what system you're running on, but several commercial Unixen default to using `ed` as the editor, instead of something sensible like `vi`.  Set `EDITOR=vi` and try again:

```
$ EDITOR=vi crontab -e
```

Which will use `vi` as your editor.  Replace `vi` with `emacs` or even [*shudder*] `pico`, whatever you're most comfortable with.

Another option is to use the file form of `crontab`:

```
$ crontab /tmp/ctab
```

Which will assign the contents of the file `/tmp/ctab` to the crontab for the current user.  You can then edit `/tmp/ctab` (the name is not important) with whatever editor you like that can save as plain text: `vi`, `emacs`, `Xcode`, `eclipse`, whatever.  First, do:

```
$ crontab -l > /tmp/ctab
```

To get a copy of the current crontab, so you can add to it (the `crontab FILE` form replaces the current crontab), then do:

```
$ crontab /tmp/ctab
```

To import the contents of `/tmp/ctab`.